# How to change babel-loader cache directory?

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

I'm using react-app-rewired, here is my `config-overrides.js`:

```
const { getBabelLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, env) => {
    getBabelLoader(config).options.cacheDirectory = 'babel-cache';
    return config;
  }
};
```

I'm trying to change a babel-loader cache directory. `babel-cache` direcory is created, but its size is just 1.5 Mb. The size of `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader` is 106 Mb.

Is it possible to save cache into the specified folder only?

Actually I'm trying to improve performance of a continuous integration process. The problem is that `npm ci` command clears `node_modules/.cache` folder. And GitLab CI/CD builds the project from scratch. Maybe it's possible to keep `node_modules/.cache` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not what I can tell from the docs.  You'll have to create a feature request or post build script to move said cache.

According to the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#options):

> `cacheDirectory`: Default `false`. When set, the given directory will be
> used to cache the results of the loader. Future webpack builds will
> attempt to read from the cache to avoid needing to run the potentially
> expensive Babel recompilation process on each run. If the value is set
> to true in options (`{cacheDirectory: true}`), the loader will use the
> default cache directory in `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader` or
> fallback to the default OS temporary file directory if no `node_modules`
> folder could be found in any root directory.

So, it's either `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader` or the OS cache directory.

Maybe you can do something with a [customer loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#customized-loader), but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right, it's easier to copy cache folder using build scripts in a CI/CD pipeline. And also it's a more universal solution, because it allows one to copy other caches as well.