# React typescript, how do I RE-TRANSPILE all the code from zero? Clean Build

Tags: typescript

I have a projected I created using `npm create-react-app --template typescript`. It has a `package.json` file with the:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Which I run using `npm start`, and everything *was* working fine.

**Only issue** is: I just had a typescript error, which wouldn't go away, and my code was correct. It turned out it was some kind of caching system problem with typescript, that was not updating/re-transpiling my file correctly, even though I was changing it.

This is very traumatizing, (imagine writing `True===True` an getting an error... exactly). So I want to know, how can I completely delete any cache from typescript, to transpile from 0. Stopping `npm start` and starting again did NOT reset typescript cache.

Answer (score 1):

In a standard Create React App (CRA) setup, I believe that the caching is being done by Webpack + Babel, not by TypeScript per se. Check `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader`.

(In my experience, the on-disk Babel cache is *almost* bulletproof - if you're running into problems that survive restarting `npm start`'s webpack-dev-server, there may be a deeper problem to investigate.)

For more information on CRA's Babel cache, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74243057/25507).

Comment: Yes, it's nerver-wracking this type of problem. It was showing a variable (a type definition to be precise) I no long had, anywhere in the entire project. But you are right, I think that's where the cache lies, and next time I will just delete these files ... (hope won't need to though)